# making random objects with NSTimer in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, random, cocos2d-iphone

Hi i'm making a game with cocos2d.I want to create random objects with `NSTimer`. The objects are stored in an `NSArray`.I'm using the following way, but every time the timer initializes the same thing is happening. Just like if random wouldn't work. I'm weird.
I would be happy if you could tell me what is wrong.  Or simply tell me how to access random objects of an array.

```
   -(id)init{
        if (self = [super init]) {
                         ....
                     timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(randomObjects) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
                         ....
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)randomObjects{

    if (!isPaused) {
        srand(time(NULL));
        int randomObjectIndex = rand()%self.ObjectCount_forThisLevel;
        NSLog(@"randomObjectIndex = %d",randomObjectIndex);
        int randomObjectID = [[self.arrayForObjects objectAtIndex:randomObjectIndex] intValue];
        NSLog(@"randomObjectID = %d",randomObjectID);
        switch (randomObjectID) {
            case kBoxObject:{
                srand(time(NULL));
                int x1 = rand()%200+100;
                [self createBoxAtLocation:CGPointMake(x1, 500)];
                break;
            }
            case kBrickObject:{
                srand(time(NULL));
                int x2 = rand()%200+100;
                [self createBrickAtLocation:CGPointMake(x2, 500)];
                break;
            }
            case kOrangeObject:{
                srand(time(NULL));
                int x3 = rand()%200+100;
                [self createOrangeAtLocation:CGPointMake(x3, 500)];
                break;
            }
            case kBoardObject:{
                srand(time(NULL));
                int x4 = rand()%200+100;
                [self createBoardAtLocation:CGPointMake(x4, 500)];
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(randomObjects) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

Comment: You say "I'm weird". I don't see how that is relevant. ;)

Comment: calling srand every time is unnecessary, once after app launched suffices. On iOS use srandom and random instead, or arc4random.

Comment: Thanks for answers, I wanted to say it's weird.

Answer (score 3):

With cocos2d, NSTimer isn't recommended mainly because it is unaffected by the build-in Pause/Resume functionality. Instead, schedule a method as follows:

```
[self schedule:@selector(randomObjects:) interval:1.0f];
```

You will also have to change the randomObjects definition to:

```
-(void)randomObjects:(ccTime)dt
```

Where dt is the actual time passed.

Lastly, instead of using rand(), use:

```
arc4random()
```

That function auto-seeds, so you don't need to worry about seeding every time.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your timer is being called from init method. Use a breakpoint to see if the program stops there.

Secondly, make the "repeats" argument "YES" to constantly get random objects:

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(randomObjects) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

If it is not being called, you might want to move it to a view controller's lifecycle method, for example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[self setTimer:[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(randomObjects) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]];
}
```

Third, remove the timer call from the "randomObjects" method --- you probably don't want to recreate the timer every time.

For accessing random indicies, try using arc4random()

```
arc4random() % 4
```

will generate 0, 1, 2 or 3

Likewise, if you have an array, and want to access random objects from it, you can do:

```
NSInteger index = arc4random() % [[self arrayForObjects] count]
YourObject* object = [self arrayForObjects][index];
```

If you want the timer to stop repeating, simply call:

```
[timer invalidate];
```

Try that out.